# Как правильно написать синтаксис?

Tags: javascript

```
 foto.style.transform = "translateX("+"-50"+"vw)";
```

вот нужно сдвинуть, я понимаю что синтаксис не такой, перебрал методом тыка все что можно но не могу понять как правильно записать.

Comment: foto.style.transform = "translateX(-50vw)". Как ссылка для изучения: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_transform.asp

Comment: Но ведь работает данный код. Что за переменная foto? На что указывает?